# Insert in an existing row

Tags: sql, insert, sql-update

How can I INSERT INTO an **empty** field **without creating a new row**?

If I understand:

I cannot use `insert` into with a `where` clause:

```
INSERT INTO consulta (tema)  
value('prova')  
WHERE client=1;
```

I can `update` with a `where` but I cannot do that if the field is empty  :

```
UPDATE consulta      
SET tema=prova  
WHERE client=1;
```

So how should I insert in an existing row?

Comment: First insert your value, and when your value exists, do the UPDATE query?

Comment: UPDATE consulta
SET tema=prova
WHERE client=''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're trying to update actually, insert into is allways intended for creation, unless you use replace into which will over write your row ONLY IF there if an old row in the table has the same value as a new row for a PRIMARY KEY or a UNIQUE index, (From [Mysql 5 reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html) But I don't know which DBMS you're using

From your update statement I see that prova doesn't have '', maybe that is your problem.

You should use:
`UPDATE consulta
SET tema='prova' WHERE client=1;`

Comment: You are right. My problem was that the word prova should have ". There is no problem to update a field even it is empty.

Answer (score 1):

Do you want one of these?

```
UPDATE consulta
SET tema=prova
WHERE client is null;
```

or

```
UPDATE consulta
SET tema=prova
WHERE client = '';
```

"Empty" doesn't have a technical meaning in SQL, so it could be either.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem may be you are missing the quotes around the value you are trying to set.

Try:

```
UPDATE consulta       
SET tema='prova'  
WHERE client=1;
```

Comment: You must use 'prova', not "prova". Be careful with that little errors.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use update statement if the row already exists
You can check the values as empty in where class. use the below query

```
update consultaSET tema='prova' WHERE tema='' and client=1
```